# Decorators and globals

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

The application has a module, `A`, which contains a decorator which adds functions to a list which is a module-level global in `A`.  The list of functions is used in other functions within the module.

**A.py**

```
import functools


things = []


def register(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        things.append(func)
        return func
    return inner


@register
def foo():pass


@register
def bar():pass


foo()
bar()

print(things)
```

This pattern has been copied in other parts of the application, so a number of modules contain the register function and the module level list.

I want to reduce the amount of duplication by having `A.register` implemented in a single location, but modules that import need to have their own local list of functions.

I tried importing `A` and creating a providing a list:

**B.py**

```
import A

things = []


@A.register
def baz():pass


@A.register
def quux():pass


baz()
quux()

print(things)
```

But all the functions are registered in `A.things`:

```
>>> import A
[<function foo at 0x7f3ecdf466e0>, <function bar at 0x7f3ecdf467d0>]
>>> import B
[]
>>> print A.things
[<function foo at 0x7f3ecdf466e0>, <function bar at 0x7f3ecdf467d0>, <function baz at 0x7f3ecdf46410>, <function quux at 0x7f3ecdf469b0>]
```

Is there a way to have single implementation of `A.register`, but to have it populate a list in the modules in which it's imported?  That is

```
>>> print A.things
[<function foo at 0x7f3ecdf466e0>, <function bar at 0x7f3ecdf467d0>] 


>>> print B.things
[<function baz at 0x7f3ecdf46410>, <function quux at 0x7f3ecdf469b0>]
```

Comment: To be honest I can not find a use case for this algorithm. However, I am giving you some advises but I can not really understand this way of using decorators.

Comment: @ElisByberi Modifying the behavior of calling a function (in this case, logging) seems [to me] like an appropriate use of decorators. A decorator is just some sugar and a function that when given a function returns a function.

Comment: @ryachza Decorators are used to modify returned value from the function. It is like writing `function = decorator(function)`. Returned value is the only behavior the function has. Others are called "side effects".

Comment: @ElisByberi Perhaps I should have been clearer - this is working code in an existing application, so regardless of the apparent quality the original design, I wish to keep my changes as minimal as possible.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Declare variable `things` in every module and use answer from [ryachza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1424121/ryachza).

Comment: @ElisByberi I agree with "`function = decorator(function)`", and that means they're for modifying the return value of the *function definition*, not the function itself. And side effects are part of the returned value anyway. That they aren't first class is a limitation of Python.

Comment: @ryachza Decorator can not modify function. Where did I say that decorator can modify function? The returned value is not a side effect, ever. This sentence does not make sense "they're for modifying the return value of the function definition".

Comment: @ElisByberi I'm unsure how you reconcile the demonstrable behavior with the opinions you hold, and I'm not interested in discussing it further.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I would appreciate any feedback on my first answer regarding whether, and if not why, it didn't work with your codebase, and I added a second answer that may work for you with less modification.

Comment: @ryachza I did reply for the sake of the conversation. You have to be cautious in using technical terms. For example: "and that means they're for modifying the return value of the function definition", function definition does not return value. Calling a function returns a value only if function is defined to return a value, defining it does not return anything. [Side effect definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a single implementation of `register()` function in module A.
You do not have variable `things` in module B, it [variable] belongs to module A only.

Even if you use decorator in module B, it is the variable `things` in module A that will be appended.

Another very important point to remember is that variable `things` will get appended every time functions are called.

**If you can not change algorithm declare variable** `things` **in every module and create a decorator like this:**

(code from [ryachza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47357848/2430448))

```
def register(things=things):
    def _register(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            things.append(func)
            return func

        return inner

    return _register
```

However, that is not the way to use decorators.

You can create a variable `things` in every module and append it like this. You do not have to use decorators for this.

```
things = []


def foo():
    pass


things.append(foo)


def bar():
    pass


things.append(bar)

foo()
bar()

print(things)
```

Comment: Append to the list after the function definition: simple and obvious, and requires less code than before.  Just goes to show, "Explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: @snakecharmerb I would argue that a function decorator *is explicit* (indirection/abstraction does not mean implicit), and that this would simply be noisy. If your objective is to get a handful of functions in a list (not when they're called, but once after defined), why not make make a list literal after they are all defined (`things = [foo,bar]`)? If you want to get *all* the top level functions in the module, I might consider something like `[x for x in globals().values() if isinstance(x,types.FunctionType)]` so as not to risk missing one with the manual tracking.

Answer (score 1):

Not identical but perhaps satisfactory, you could define `register` like:

```
def register(things=things):
  def _register(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
      things.append(func)
      return func
    return inner
  return _register
```

Used in `A` like:

```
@register()
def foo():pass

@register()
def bar():pass
```

And in `B` like:

```
@A.register(things)
def baz():pass

@A.register(things)
def quux():pass
```

And if needed, even something like:

```
@A.register(A.things)
def whatever():pass
```

Comment: Compounding the original code's dubious use of decorators and globals with mutable default parameters - I like it ;-)  As Elis Byberi observes, as it stands this code would result in a function being added to `things` every time it's called, but this is easily remedied by making things a `set` instead of a `list`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Ah I misunderstood then. I thought that you were *trying* to log every call to the function so that you can review relative order of execution and number of calls.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to my other answer that might require less modification to your existing code would be changing module `B` like:

```
...
things = []
A.things = things

@A.register
def baz():pass
...
```

Essentially anything you have a reference to is mutable (`A.things` in this case). You could of course save a reference to the original `A.things` and swap between within a single module if needed.